# How can I catch a specific value with JSON Deserialize?

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I catch a JSON with .NET:

```
string result = json_serializer.Deserialize(myJSON);
```

well the structure of JSON is such as:

```
result
    data[0]
        user
            bio
            name
            nickname
    data[1]
        user
            bio
            name
            nickname    
    data[2]
        user
            bio
            name
            nickname
```

and I'd like to get only the first nickname (as string) that have some value: I mean, it is not null and is not empty.

How can I do it?

Comment: could you post 1 example of your json input

Comment: I wrote as the json looks like!

Comment: @markzzz no, you haven't. Json could look like `{ "result": [ {"bio": "blah", "name": "foo", "nickname": "bar"}]}`

Comment: The purpose is to copy your example to run instead of building again your json string, it takes time for us

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: yes, is how I wrote it :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you would want something like this,

```
public string FirstUserNickname(string JsonUserInfo) 
{
    JavaScriptSerializer JsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    ResultData Results = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResultData>(JsonUserInfo);
    foreach (UserInfo UserInfo in Results.result)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserInfo.nickname))
            return UserInfo.nickname;
    }
    return null;
}

public class ResultData
{
    public List<UserInfo> result;
}

public class UserInfo
{
    public string bio;
    public string name;
    public string nickname;
}
```

This will achieve your goal and is a strongly typed approach, using the `JavaScriptSerializer` class from the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly, more info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337495%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Linq to JSON](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json) (search NuGet for Newtonsoft Json). Assume your JSON looks like:

```
{ "result": [ { "bio": "foo", "name": "Robin", "nickname": "Moll" },
              { "bio": "bar", "name": "Ted", "nickname": "DoctorZ" },
              { "bio": "moo", "name": "Barney", "nickname": "Wait4it" } ]
}
```

Then getting name of first user:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
var name = (string)jo["result"][0]["name"]; // Robin
```

Of course if it is possible that you will not have any users, then you should verify that user exists:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
var user = jo["result"].FirstOrDefault();
if (user != null)
    name = (string)user["name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Linq to JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) you can deserialize to .net objects, like so:

```
Result deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
```

After that you can use LINQ to query the objects:

```
User nicknameduser = deserializedResult.Users
  .FirstOrDefault(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.nickname))
if (nicknameduser == null) return null;
return nicknameduser.nickname;
```